# Have non-periodic radio signals been analyzed for shannon entropy or put on a Zipf plot?

Tags: radio-astronomy, seti

If aliens did exist, they would probably compress their communications. And they might use a fault tolerant infrastructure like TCP/IP. In either scenario, real communications would not be periodic but closer to random noise. Has anyone performed a Zipf plot or calculated shannon entropy of non-periodic radio signals?

Comment: What research have you done on this question? Even a quick google finds papers.

Comment: Did you look at the seti project?

Comment: Almost all the data use narrow band signals. When we use fiber for maximum throughput, we developed frequency ,multiplexed and time multiplexed strategies. CDMA and GSM allow multiple users over a spread of frequencies. If intelligent life was communicating, they would look to use similar cost saving features. As for sending out a periodic analog signal, why would any alien pay for that? What's the ROI for pissing into space?